# Rotate text of the title in UberAccordion

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a responsive Accordion using the link

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXnJ8/25/)
/*
 * UberAccordion
 *
 * Gabriel Aszalos
 *
*/

(function($) {

```
var UberAccordion = function(parent, options) {

    // Default settings

    var defaults = {
        verticalClass    : 'accordion-vertical',    // Class to apply when orientation is vertical
        horizontalClass  : 'accordion-horizontal',  // Class to apply when orientation is horizontal
        activeSlideClass : 'active',                // Class to apply on active accordion slide
        orientation      : 'vertical',              // Accordion orientation
        orientationQuery : '(max-width: 700px)',    // Media query which causes orientation change
        startSlide       : 1,                       // Starter slide
        openMultiple     : false,                   // Set to true for multiple open slides at a time
        autoPlay         : false,                   // Auto-play
        autoPlaySpeed    : 5000,                    // Auto-play interval
        slideEvent       : 'click',                 // Open slide event
        animationSpeed   : 333,                     // Animation Speed
        headerItem       : typeof options.headerClass === 'undefined' ? 'h1' : '.' + options.headerClass,     // Header class
        contentItem      : typeof options.contentClass === 'undefined' ? 'div' : '.' + options.contentClass   // Content class
    };

    var settings  = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);                  // Add user settings with overwrite
    var el        = parent.children('ul');                                  // Accordion container
    var slides    = el.children().children(settings.contentItem);           // Accordion slides
    var headers   = el.children('li').children(settings.headerItem);        // Accordion headers
    var state     = {};                                                     // Keeps current accordion state (ie. currentSlide, orientation, etc)

    var showSlideCallback = function() {
        el.trigger('ua-slide-changed');
    }

    this.toggleSlide = function(slideNumber, override) {

        if(!settings.openMultiple) {

            // If multiple is disabled, open current slide and close other

            if(slideNumber !== state.currentSlide || override) {
                this.hideSlide($(slides[el.children('li.' + settings.activeSlideClass).index()]));
                this.showSlide($(slides[slideNumber]));
            }

        } else {

            // If multiple is enabled, toggle clicked slide

            if($(slides[slideNumber]).parent().hasClass(settings.activeSlideClass)) {
                this.hideSlide($(slides[slideNumber]));
            } else {
                this.showSlide($(slides[slideNumber]));
            }
        }

        state.currentSlide = slideNumber;
    }

    this.showSlide = function(slide) {

        if(state.orientation === "horizontal") {
            slide.slideDown(settings.animationSpeed, showSlideCallback);
        } else {
            slide.parent().animate({
                width: slide.parent().attr('data-width')
            }, settings.animationSpeed, showSlideCallback);
        }

        slide.parent().addClass(settings.activeSlideClass);
    }

    this.hideSlide = function(slide) {
        if(state.orientation === "horizontal") {
            slide.slideUp(settings.animationSpeed);
        } else {
            slide.parent().animate({
                width: slide.parent().children(settings.headerItem).attr('data-width')
            }, settings.animationSpeed);
        }

        slide.parent().removeClass(settings.activeSlideClass);
    }

    this.setOrientation = function(orientation) {

        el.removeClass(settings.horizontalClass + ' ' + settings.verticalClass);

        switch(orientation) {
            case 'vertical':
                el.addClass(settings.verticalClass);
                $('p').html('switch vertical mode');
                installVertical();
                break;

            case 'horizontal':
                el.addClass(settings.horizontalClass);

                // Don't wipe styles on first load

                if(typeof state.orientation !== 'undefined') {
                    uninstallVertical();
                }

                $('p').html('switch horizontal mode');
                applyHorizontalBase();

                break;
        }

        $(slides[state.currentSlide])
            .show()
            .parent().addClass(settings.activeSlideClass);

        state.orientation = orientation;
    }

    this.setAutoplay = function(enabled) {

        var _this = this;

        if(enabled) {
            state.autoPlayInterval = setInterval(function() {
                var totalSlides = el.children('li').children(settings.headerItem).length;
                state.currentSlide = state.currentSlide < (totalSlides - 1) ? state.currentSlide + 1 : 0;
                _this.toggleSlide(state.currentSlide, true);
            }, settings.autoPlaySpeed);
        } else {
            if(typeof state.autoPlayInterval !== "undefined") {
                clearInterval(state.autoPlayInterval);
            }
        }
    }

    // Installs styling and events for vertical slider

    var installVertical = function() {

        uninstallVertical();

        $(window).bind('resize', resizeContainer);

        applyVerticalBase();
        calculateSizes();
    }

    var applyVerticalBase = function() {

        slides.parent().css(CSSObject.SlideContainers);

        CSSObject.Headers.functions.setTransforms(-$(headers[0]).outerHeight(), 0);
        CSSObject.Slides.functions.setHeight(el.outerHeight(true));
        CSSObject.Slides.functions.setLeft($(headers[0]).outerHeight(true));

        headers.css(CSSObject.Headers.defaults);
        headers.setOuterWidth(el.innerHeight());
        slides.css(CSSObject.Slides.defaults);
    }

    var applyHorizontalBase = function() {
        slides.css({ 'display': 'none' });
    }

    // Calculate sizes and save widths in data attributes
    // for safe animating

    var calculateSizes = function() {

        var totalHeaderWidth = 0;
        var currentContainer = el.children('li.' + settings.activeSlideClass);
        var currentHeader    = currentContainer.children(settings.headerItem);
        var parentWidth      = parent.innerWidth();

        var slideWidth, headerWidth;

        headers.each(function() {
            headerWidth = $(this).outerHeight(true);
            totalHeaderWidth += headerWidth;

            $(this).parent().width(headerWidth);
            $(this).attr('data-width', headerWidth);
        });

        slides.each(function() {
            slideWidth  = parentWidth - totalHeaderWidth;
            headerWidth = $(this).parent().children(settings.headerItem).outerHeight(true);

            $(this).setOuterWidth(slideWidth);
            $(this).attr('data-width', slideWidth);

            $(this).parent().attr('data-width', slideWidth + headerWidth - 1);
        });

        currentContainer.width(parentWidth - totalHeaderWidth + currentHeader.outerHeight(true) - 1);

    }

    // Called on resize event - adjusts accordion width according
    // to parent to allow fluid design

    var resizeContainer = function() {

        if(state.orientation === "vertical") {

            // If we don't hide the accordion before reading the parent's width value
            // the parent will not auto-adjust in width

            el.css('display', 'none');
            el.width(parent.innerWidth());
            el.css('display', 'block');

            calculateSizes();
        }
    }

    // Uninstalls vertical events and styles

    var uninstallVertical = function() {

        $(window).unbind('resize', resizeContainer);

        el.removeAttr('style');
        el.children('li').removeAttr('style');
        slides.removeAttr('style');

        headers.removeAttr('style');
    }

    // Constructor

    var initialize = function(scope) {

        if(typeof options.headerClass !== 'undefined' && typeof options.contentClass === 'undefined') {
            throw("Content class must be defined along with header class.");
        }

        el.addClass('uberAccordion');

        headers.on(settings.slideEvent, function(e) {
            scope.toggleSlide(el.children('li').children(settings.headerItem).index(this));
            scope.setAutoplay(false);

            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });

        // If set to responsive, handle orientation changes

        if(settings.orientationQuery) {
            state.matchesQuery = window.matchMedia(settings.orientationQuery).matches;

            // If media query match state changes, switch orientation
            $(window).resize(function() {
                if(window.matchMedia(settings.orientationQuery).matches !== state.matchesQuery) {
                    state.matchesQuery = window.matchMedia(settings.orientationQuery).matches;
                    scope.setOrientation(state.orientation === 'vertical' ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical');
                }
            });

            if(state.matchesQuery) {
                settings.orientation = settings.orientation === 'vertical' ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical';
            }
        }

        state.currentSlide = settings.startSlide - 1;
        $(slides[state.currentSlide]).parent().addClass(settings.activeSlideClass);

        scope.setOrientation(settings.orientation);

        // Set-up auto-play if enabled

        if(settings.autoPlay && !settings.openMultiple) {
            scope.setAutoplay(true);
        }

        el.attr('data-accordion-active', "true");
    }

    initialize(this);
}

$.fn.uberAccordion = function(options) {

    // Avoid double instantiating

    return $(this).children("ul").attr('data-accordion-active') === "true" ? false : new UberAccordion(this, options);
}

// Set total width with padding and borders (outerWidth)

$.fn.setOuterWidth = function(value) {
    $(this).each(function() {
        var paddingLeft = isNaN(parseInt($(this).css('padding-left'), 10)) || $(this).css('padding-left') === '100%' ? 0 : parseInt($(this).css('padding-left'), 10);
        var paddingRight = isNaN(parseInt($(this).css('padding-right'), 10)) || $(this).css('padding-right') === '100%' ? 0 : parseInt($(this).css('padding-right'), 10);
        var borderLeft = isNaN(parseInt($(this).css('border-left-width'), 10)) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).css('border-left-width'), 10);
        var borderRight = isNaN(parseInt($(this).css('border-right-width'), 10)) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).css('border-right-width'), 10);

        $(this).width(value - paddingLeft - paddingRight - borderLeft - borderRight);
    });
}

// CSS Object for vertical accordion
// These base styles are necessary for all vertical accordions

var CSSObject = {

    SlideContainers: {
        'display': 'inline',
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'float': 'left',
        'height': '100%',
        'position': 'relative'
    },

    Headers: {

        defaults: {
            'display': 'block',
            'float': 'left',
            'white-space': 'nowrap',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0',
            'left': '0',
            'transform-origin': '0 100% 0',
            '-webkit-transform-origin': '0 100%',
            '-moz-transform-origin': '0 100%',
            '-ms-transform-origin': '0 100%'
        },

        functions: {
            setTransforms: function(x, y) {
                CSSObject.Headers.defaults['-webkit-transform'] = "rotate(90deg) translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
                CSSObject.Headers.defaults['-moz-transform'] = "rotate(90deg) translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
                CSSObject.Headers.defaults['-ms-transform'] = "rotate(90deg) translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
                CSSObject.Headers.defaults['-sand-transform'] = "rotate(90deg) translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
                CSSObject.Headers.defaults['transform'] = "rotate(90deg) translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
                //CSSObject.Headers.defaults['filter'] = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)";
            }
        }
    },

    Slides: {

        defaults: {
            'float': 'left',
            'height': 0,
            'display': 'block',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0'
        },

        functions: {
            setHeight: function(height) { CSSObject.Slides.defaults.height = height; },
            setLeft: function(left) { CSSObject.Slides.defaults.left = left; }
        }
    }
}

$('.accordionContainer').uberAccordion({
headerClass: 'title',
contentClass: 'content'
```

});

}(jQuery));

Here I wanted to set the title part of each div facing its own content without affecting the toggled view.

For example the title Slider1 facing itsown content, Slider2 to its content and so on.
I have tried Changing the Angle in

```
CSSObject.Headers.defaults['transform'] = "rotate(90deg) translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
```

But only changing to horizontal position.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Text can be rotated using transform property of CSS3. Please check this link:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: But While giving 270 degree the title bar itself is disappearing.I dont know why

Comment: Rotating it to 90 degree will change it from hrizontal to vertical. Check following link for vertical tabs: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-content-accordion/